# MySQL - Can't create table (errno: 150) - Foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, constraints, cascade

I want to create these 3 tables in my MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);


CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    product_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (category_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The problem is with the last table. I get an error:

> 1005 - Can't create table 'test1.categories_products' (errno:
>   150)

But when i try to create it without the constraints  it works.

```
CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    product_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id)
);
```

I need the constraints in case a product or a category is removed. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: no it's not it. This was a typo. I tried it again and i still get the same error.

Comment: I edited my post. The error was not caused by the typo.

Comment: @nlsbshtr That was it. This is really embarrassing... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo

```
CREATE TABLE product
```

(singular)

and then referencing

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
```

(plural).

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);


CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    product_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (category_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

You created "product" but referenced "products".

By the way, you should create an ID column and use this one as primary key in "categories_products" and add a second (unique) index on both columns. This is best practice and INNODB does internally create an ID column anyway so...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for the "good practice" tip.

Comment: The only reason to create "an ID" column on `categories_products` would be if a product can be assigned to more than one category. If that is not the case, creating an artificial primary key only adds overhead to the table (because you now have two indexes instead of just one) without bringing any advantage.

Comment: In this specific case, where the columns of the unique index cannot be null, it is overhead, yes. Nevertheless in cases where such an index is not available, InnoDB would create a column to comply with internal needs, see e.g. [link](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/). Thus I think it's good attitude to create the column in all cases.